# What will be my NOC for these job duties

Tags: immigration, canada, express-entry

I am applying for Express Entry Canada. I need to find my NOC Code but cannot find a title that matches my job duties, which are as follows:

In the job, I was given some data in Excel files about the products uploaded on the website, and I manually confirmed on the website whether the information was correctly being reflected. And then if I found any discrepancy, I would open a ticket and follow up with the website representatives to resolve the matter.

The title was "Marketplace Associate".

Company termed the work as "Quality Assurance".

Comment: Someone can feel free to correct me but 2171 – Information systems analysts and consultants is the closest match I could find.

Comment: Thanks. It seems close enough but still too far from my actual job role. I think it would fall under NOC C or D since it was a low skills job not requiring a degree.